# Razorpay not returning payment id using order id

Tags: php, payment-gateway, razorpay

I need razorpay_payment_id using razorpay_order_id. But,

When I use this the response is

```
$order = $api->order->fetch("order_xxxxxxxxxx")->payments;
var_dump($order);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTDWE.jpg)

```
Notice: Undefined index: payments in D:\wamp\www\xxxxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxx\razorpay-php\src\Resource.php on line 40
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0010  139848  {main}( )   ..\test.php:0
2   3.0040  772824  Razorpay\Api\Resource->__get( ) ..\test.php:981
```

null

```
$order = $api->order->fetch("order_xxxxxxxxxx")->payments();
var_dump($order);

object(Razorpay\Api\Collection)[8]
protected 'attributes' => 
array (size=3)
'entity' => string 'collection' (length=10)
'count' => int 1
'items' => 
array (size=1)
0 => 
object(Razorpay\Api\Payment)[10]
...
```

Not getting payment id and payment details.

Comment: I suppose details are in first element of `items`?

Comment: Is this is the right way to access? echo $payments->items["id"];

Comment: I don't know, try and tell us.

Comment: Fond the solution, 
$orderId="order_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$payments = $api->order->fetch($orderId)->payments();

echo $payments->items[0]->id;

Comment: You can answer your own question if you want)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can easily get the payment details as a single dimensional array using -

```
$api->payment->fetch($id)
```

where $id is the razorpayment_id instead you are using long solution .

Answer (score 0):

I got solution by using this

> $payment = $api->payment->fetch($_REQUEST['razorpay_payment_id']) ;;
>
> print_r($payment->contact);